# WooCommerce: Fatal Error_Call to a member function get_items() on boolean

Tags: woocommerce, boolean, fatal-error, sendinblue

I am experiencing a serious issue in relation to the mail service plugin and my website’s service is putting onto a halt because of this.

I am currently using Sendinblue’s plugin (both its standalone and its woocommerce addon). However, with these activated, woocommerce no longer sends out email automatically regarding new member, forgot password and I cant even preview the email template under Woocommerce’s setting page.

The error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_items() on boolean in /home/lobuti91/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-sendinblue-newsletter-subscription/woocommerce-sendinblue.php on line 562

Please help me on this. Sendinblue refused to admit this is their fault after having it inspected by their technicians!

Comment: This looks like a bug in woocommerce-sendinblue-newsletter-subscription plugin. **This plugin need to be updated**, as it uses badly the get_item() method on a non object… **You need** to disable this plugin ***(or move it by ftp, out of the plugin folder)***, to get back your web site working.

Comment: Thanks. I gave up using them.

Answer (score -3):

This error occur when order don't have object. So please

```
$order_detail = wc_get_order($order_id);
```

this $order_detail have no object of order because order id is not accessible.

Comment: This answer seems to have no direct link to the question. If it does then it's not obvious to the reader and needs more comments/annotation.